# How to insert crawling in database in python

Tags: python

I have been crawling data from Fc Barcelona website, just get player biodata. Then I want to store data that have been crawling in a database. But, I got an error in the database, my database just show variable like player_name, player_number, player_position not data inside those?

I access a database by running my XAMPP control panel

==========my code=============

```
import mysql.connector

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

my_url='https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/football/first-team/players'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"team-person__info"})

db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="pemain_barca"
)

for container in containers:

    name_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"team-person__large-name"})
    player_name = name_container[0].text

    number_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"team-person__number"})
    player_number = number_container[0].text

    position_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"team-person__position-meta"})
    player_position = position_container[0].text

    print("Name: " + player_name)
    print("Number: " + player_number)
    print("Position: " + player_position)    
    print(" ")

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO pemain (player_name, player_number, player_position) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"    
values = [ ("player_name", "player_number", "player_position") ]  
cursor.execute(sql, values)
db.commit()
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? You ask how to store the data but have an insert statement so that doesn't appear to be exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Set-up your `XAMPP` db to accept connections. Add those configurations to your `db = mysql.connector.connect(....` and that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your `values` the constant strings and not the data that you extracted?

```
values = [ ("player_name", "player_number", "player_position") ]
```

This will make the values stored be **literally** `player_name`, `player_number`, and `player_position`.

`values` should be the variables that contain the data:

```
values = [ (player_name, player_number, player_position) ]
```

Comment: Need to append each set of player details inside the loop to get all player data